# Convert String to decimal (18, 2) in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Converting String to Decimal (18,2)

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

DF1 = DF.withColumn("New_col", DF["New_col"].cast(DecimalType(12,2)))

display(DF1)
```

[expected and actual O/P i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knJTU.png)

Need help in converting the String to decimal to load the DF into Database.

Comment: please post a sample of the `df`

Answer (score 6):

You need to get rid of the commas before casting:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

DF1 = DF.withColumn('New_col', F.regexp_replace('New_col', ',', '').cast('decimal(12,2)'))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is worked fine for me:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType

DF1 = DF.withColumn("New_col", DF["New_col"].cast(DecimalType(precision=12, scale=2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
DF1=DF.withColumn("New_Col",col("New_Col").cast(DecimalType(18,2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do this as well.

```
DF.withColumn("New_Col",col("New_Col").cast(decimal(18,2)))
```

Assuming the Above DF as pyspark dataframe

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the type of the column like this:

```
import pandas as pd
DF["New_col"] = pd.to_numeric(DF["New_col"])
```